# Doubt about Bitcoin SCI

Tags: wallet.dat, shopping-cart-interface

What's up guys... I'm trying to figure out what's the best shopping card interface I should use. I want a PHP based, simple to work with. Was looking on bitfreak sci, looks good, but the negative point is that the client need to keep the session openned until the server recognize the payment (at least for what I understood, if I'm wrong correct me). So, 2 things I want to know: have any other SCI that the client don't need to keep session openned for the payment to be recognized? I know the bitcoin payments take some time to be validate, but some SCI that don't work with the user's browser session. Let's suppose a user make payment and just close his browser, it still able to recognize his payment?
And other question is about the addresses created by the SCI... How can I access those addresses to pick up the money?

Answer (score 1):

> but the negative point is that the client need to keep the session openned until the server recognize the payment (at least for what I understood, if I'm wrong correct me)

My Bitcoin SCI script doesn't stop processing the payment if the session expires. It will just start a new session. The session variables are used in the script to hold temporary data which can be recovered if the session expires. But if the client IP changes it will not allow the transaction to complete for obvious reasons. If the client closes the page they will be able to complete the transaction but only if they saved the URL of the transaction page and if their IP address hasn't changed. In the case where the client pays and then leaves the page before completing the transaction you have several options, but it really depends on how you integrate the script into your own site.

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct to assume you mean shopping *cart* interface? If so I have a good recommendation. I am not affiliated with coinpayments.net besides being a very happy customer of theirs. They charge 0.5% + network fee to process a payment and send it to the address of your choice or hold it for you until you decide where to withdraw it to. They do all the payment processing for A LOT of coins and have tons of shopping cart plugins: https://www.coinpayments.net/merchant-tools-plugins

For a while I was trying to get coinbase API to work, as they charge 0% to process the "first $1,000,000" :P but it's only bitcoin and I ended up wasting days trying to configure it and get their support team to send me a valid certificate. Coinbase is great for converting to USD but their merchant services are a bit lacking. Coinpayments has amazing support and unless you're processing $100,000s 0.5% is absolutely worth it.

Edit: They also will process the payment even if a client makes a payment to you and then leaves the page. Their sessions last 5 hours which can be risky during a big crash but I have not had any problems with them.